# Pip Django Version Different than Python's

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to complete the Django tutorial found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

However, when I try to run `python manage.py migrate` I get the error `Unknown command: 'migrate'`. I looked this up and discovered that this means I am using a version of Django that doesn't support migrate. So I ran `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` to see what version of Django Python was using. Turns out it's 1.6.1. This doesn't make sense though because when I do `pip list` I get Django (1.9.2). If I look in my settings.py file it even says "Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1."

Does anyone know why Python is using a different version of Django than is installed using pip?

Comment: Are you executing the command to check the version in the same virtualenv as you executed `pip` in? Are you using virtualenvs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly recommended that you run Django in a virtual environment as it will make managing Django a lot easier, and you don't want to mess with the python version on your system.

use `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>` to use virtualenv with a specific python version.

Then `pip install Django` to get the latest version of Django.

**Edit:**

Don't forget that when you're messing with Django settings and files, that you need to activate your virtualenv in your command prompt.

Type
 `source myprojectenv/bin/activate` and your prompt should change to

`(myprojectenv)user@host:~/myproject$`

Comment: I created a virtualenv and I am running everything from that and it appears to work now. I am still confused as to why this doesn't work when I use django from the global python installation. Is it possible that Matej is right and different Django versions are installed for different Python versions?

Comment: @ChrisWillis That's possible. I've had problems where Django was on python2.7 but I installed pip for python3.5 in a server environment and weird errors. Virtualenv made things a lot easier. You can use `python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"` to see where django is on your system (which will indicate the python version in your system path.)

Comment: @ChrisWillis Checkout my edit too. Sometimes I would try to run "python manage.py runserver" or a different command, and I would get a ton of errors because virtualenv wasn't activated in my command prompt.

Comment: I have just been targeting the virtualenv's python instance using absolute paths. It's good to know that you can use that activate command though. I ran that django path command and got `['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django']` shouldn't that mean it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your using diferent version of python python2 and python3 can have diffent versions of libraries. Try run `python3 manage.py migrate`